# Fourier coefficients, and density of a subspace

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

We have $\hat f(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(e^{it})e^{-int}dt$ for each $f\in L^2(T)$ and for each $n\in \mathbb Z$.

Now define $\Lambda_n f=\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\hat f(k)$ and set $S=\left \{ f:\lim \Lambda_n f \ \text {exists}\right \}$.

The claim is that  $S$ is dense in $L^2(T)$ and of the first category.

Here is my argument:

For the first part, considering real and imaginary parts separately, using the definition of the Lebesgue measure and a density argument, it suffices to take $f=\chi_{(a,b)}$, the characteristic function of the interval $(a,b)\subset (-\pi, \pi).$. Then, $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\chi_{(a,b)}\cos {nt}dt=\frac{1}{n}(\sin nb-\sin na)$ and similarly for $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\chi_{(a,b)}\sin {nt}dt$.

By Dirichlet's Test, using the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^m \sin(nt)=\frac{\sin(mt/2)\sin((m+1)t/2)}{\sin (t/2)},\ $ so that $\vert\sum_{n=1}^m \sin(nt)\vert\leq \frac{1}{\vert\sin (t/2)\vert},\ $it's not hard to show that these series converge. This proves that $\chi _{(a,b)}\in S.$

For the second part, we observe that if $S$ is of the second category, then we may apply Banach-Steinhaus to $\left \{ \Lambda_n \right \}_n$, to say that $S=L^2(T)$, which is a contradiction because it is well-known that there are Fourier series that are not convergent in $L^1$; i.e. the Fourier coefficients are not summable.

My questions are: is my proof correct? If not, can you supply a hint or two? Is there a more elementary way to prove the claim?

edit: the exercise as posed, does not assume any knowledge of Fourier Analysis.

Comment: You haven't said why the Fourier series of $\chi_{(a,b)}$ converges at $0$. Is the argument for that well enough known in your situation that you can stop after computing the Fourier coefficients? If you know that the space of continuously differentiable functions is dense in $L^2(T)$, that gives a simpler argument, for the series of Fourier coefficients of such functions is absolutely convergent. Re example, consider for example $f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} e^{inx}$.

Comment: Why is showing convergence at $0$ necessary here?  $\chi \in L^2(T)$ is clear and my calculation shows that $\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\hat f(k)$ converges, so $\chi \in S$. Wouldn't the series converge at $0$ unless $a$ or $b$ were $0$ and then the series would converge to $1/2?$.

Comment: You should look at the [Dirichlet kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_kernel) showing that if $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [-\epsilon,\epsilon]$ then $\sum_n \hat{f}(n)$ converges. And it is clear that the functions being zero in the neighborhood of $x= 0$ are dense in $L^2(\mathbb{T})$

Comment: Trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L^2$ and of course each of them is in $S.$

Comment: Yes this is true but I should have specified that the exercise is posed without supposing any knowledge of Fourier Analysis. It's from a chapter on Baire, Banach, Banach-Steinhaus, etc.

Comment: Why does your calculation show that $\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\hat f(k)$ converges?

Comment: $\sum_{k = -n}^n \hat{f}(k)$ is a partial sum of the Fourier series evaluated at $0$. So saying $\lim \Lambda_n f$ exists is saying that the (symmetric) Forier series converges at $0$. The Fourier series of $\chi_{(a,b)}$ converges at all points, so $\chi_{(a,b)} \in S$, that's true. But by what argument is it true?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I calculated them to be, considering real and imaginary parts $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\chi_{(a,b)}\cos {kt}dt=\frac{1}{n}(\sin kb-\sin ka)$,and similarly for the sine. These series converge. I know the results are easy if we appeal to some basic Fourier Analysis, but I want to use as little of this as possible, to follow the spirit of the exercise.

Comment: Yes, they converge, but *how do you know that?*. Unless these series have been covered **just before** in the course, you need to give a reason for their convergence. "These converge by proposition 4 of chapter 3", or something of the sort.

Comment: I see. It's just an application of Dirichlet's Test isn't it? I will edit the post.